# Cannot get the latest version of maven plugin

Tags: maven, plugins, intellij-idea, maven-plugin

I am new to maven, I have write my own maven plugin with the pom file

```
<groupId>com.xxx.api</groupId>
<artifactId>xxx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>maven-plugin</packaging>
```

then, in my IDE (intellij) I used clean install to install my maven plugin

and in the main project, my maven plugin works fine.

However, when I modify my maven plugin by adding parameter to my mojo and "mvn clean install" , 
(the groupId,artifactId,version keep the same) it supposed to be the latest version.

However, in the main project, when I try to use the latest maven plugin, I always get the old version
i.e I cannot configure the parameter that I just add to my maven plugin (because it is not exist!)

I have try to delete the maven plugin in my .m2 repo, before I install the latest version of my maven plugin, it still not work.

Any solution that I can get the latest version of my maven plugin by keeping the same
(groupId, artifactId,version)?

thanks,

Zach

Comment: Why do you need to write your own plugin? What is the purpose of your plugin? To write plugins you should write unit and in particular integration tests which is not a simple job if you know how maven works which seemed to be not the case.

Answer (score 0):

Check how the using project is configured. I guess it has its own lib/classes folder. I would suspect that your project has a copy of the older version of the plugin in its lib folder. If so, that is where it is getting the old version. Clean it out from there, i.e. you need to clean the using project.